# Javascript onclick/addEventListener sem função anônima

Tags: javascript, html, aplicação-web, funções, javascript-eventos

Estou com um problema no onclick/addEventListener do javascript, já tentei de várias formas diferentes e nenhuma surtiu resultado, eu queria que meu evento de click fosse igual a uma função já declarada e não igual a uma função anônima, mas eu não estou conseguindo fazer isso de forma limpa no código.

O que eu preciso é:

```
botao.onclick = criaObjeto(parametro);

function criaObjeto(parametro) {
    //cria objeto
}
```

ou

```
botao.addEventListener("click", criaObjeto(parametro));

function criaObjeto(parametro){
    //cria objeto
}
```

Nenhuma destas duas formas funcionou, eu realmente não gostaria de fazer algo do tipo:

```
botao.onclick = function (){
    criaObjeto(parametro);
)};
```

Pois quebra a ideia de código limpo, mas nenhuma das alternativas que eu tentei funcionou, ele simplesmente não reconhece o evento. O evento de click acontece assim que a aplicação inicia e não funciona posteriormente, logo não funciona como click, mas sim como uma função normal declarada no escopo do código.

O terminal não dispara nenhum erro em momento algum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tens de criar uma função que retorne outra, ou fazes `bind` desse argumento que precisas usar.

`#1` - `criaObjeto` retorna uma função

```
function criaObjeto(param){
    return function(evento){ // <-- esta função será chamada pelo `addEventListener`
         // e aqui dentro tens acesso ao evento gerado, e a "param"

    }
}
```

`#2` - `criaObjeto` recebe `parametro` via `.bind()`

```
var criaObjeto = function(param, evento){
    // aqui dentro tens acesso a "param" e "evento" também

}.bind(null, parametro);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou!